# Adding UIToolbar programmatically

Tags: ios, ios4

What am I doing wrong here ? I just don't see the toolbar at the bottom of screen Here's my code.

```
CGRect rect = self.view.frame;

UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(rect.origin.x,
                                                                 rect.size.height-44,
                                                                 rect.size.width,
                                                                 44)];
self.bottomToolbar = toolBar;
[toolBar release];
[_bottomToolbar setBackgroundImage:nil
                forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionBottom
                        barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[self.view addSubview:_bottomToolbar];
```

Comment: did you try [self.parentViewController.view addSubview:_bottomtoolbar];?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the toolbar's `autosizingMask` to the "flexible top margin" value.

Also, your code deals with the `toolBar` variable, the `bottomToolbar` property, and the `_bottomToolbar` ivar. Either use the property or the ivar. It's confusing to use both like you are.

Comment: `autorisingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin` worked

Answer (score 1):

there is missing one line, its sizeToFit or makeKeyAndVisible() 
Just look in the example in the ViewControllerProgrammingGuide

Comment: Do you use a NavigationController in your App? Or Tabbar?